# Sending SMS to mobile phones via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript. I would like to develop a JavaScript to send SMS to mobiles from my laptop or my mobile (java enabled though computer option would be better). Can anybody help me?

Comment: First thing to know: **Java** and **JavaScript** are two completely different things.

Comment: yup that was a mistake.........sorry

Comment: @Steven how you have solved your problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try these guys:
http://www.zeepmobile.com/blog/?p=17

OR

Cellular carriers assign email addresses to their phone numbers and support SMS by email.

So if you can email, you can text.

format :  (subscriber 10 digit number)@sms_providerdomain.xxx

Alltel  @message.alltel.com
AT&T    @txt.att.net
Nextel  @messaging.nextel.com
Sprint  @messaging.sprintpcs.com
SunCom  @tms.suncom.com
T-mobile    @tmomail.net
VoiceStream @voicestream.net
Verizon @vtext.com (text only) 
@vzwpix.com (pictures and videos)

Comment: I want to send SMS using JS and my phone SMS provider. You know a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Phonegap SMS Plugin](https://github.com/javatechig/phonegap-sms-plugin) to send SMS messages and also see [this](http://javatechig.com/phonegap/android-sms-sending-plugin-for-phonegap/).

Answer (score 0):

I also created an open source API + Phone app that will allow you to programmatically send SMS messages from an android phone using an HTTP API. Check it out on GitHub. https://github.com/NdoleStudio/httpsms