# Sending an SMS from mobile via HTML5/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, windows-8

I'm creating a web application for mobile devices that will be downloaded in one of the markets with a mini web server and run on any OS ( iOS , android , Windows8 , etc. ) .

I want an application to be as independent as possible of the OS. I only wanted to use `HTML5` and `JavaScript` .

The application allows a user to make a number of orders just by clicking buttons. Example : [List contacts ]

I need to click [List contacts ] and is sent a text message automatically to other mobile device with an android application that receives the request and sends the response via sms . The response has to be read by my web application . The application can be able to work without network / Wifi .

I've been searching and I only found ways to open the native application for sending sms.

I see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367225/sending-sms-to-mobile-phones-via-javascript), but I want to create my own way to send sms without dependencies of other applications.

Is there any way to make this submission automatically?

Or can I use/create some plugin to use on JavaScript to do that?

[EDIT] Can [this](http://www.w3.org/2012/sysapps/messaging/#h2_introduction) might be a possibility? Can someone explain me?

Comment: no, you can't send a SMS, just compose it and the user have to click the send button.

Comment: can i use/create some plugin to use in javascript to do that?

Comment: to compose an SMS? with an a tag <a href="sms://+3490322111?body=Interested%20in%20Product%20AA2">
More info for producto AA2</a>. I thin window.location = "sms://+3490322111?body=Interested%20in%20Product%20AA2" might work too

Comment: No, some plugin who sends the sms, using native sms sender and use that plugin on JS.

Comment: are you using phonegap or something like that?

Comment: For now no but it is a possibility.

Comment: if you use phonegap you can use the SMS plugin to send SMS, but that's only possible on android, on iOS you can only compose the SMS and the user have to manually send it, not sure about W8. The other alternative is to use webservices to send the SMS such as twilio, but each SMS sent cost you money

Comment: I need to send the SMS mandatorily on the phone. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then it's only possible on android using phonegap and a plugin, on iOS you can just compose the SMS and the user have to press the send button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the essential information was already mentioned in the comments, but my 2c here anyway.

As already commented, with current modern mobile operating systems apps don't get unlimited access to SMS functionality. From the user point of view allowing this would be potentially quite a hazard, since SMS's usually cost money and user should be in control of such activity, instead of having a random app sending and receiving SMS's freely (without user knowing it). Android is a bit more flexible regarding this kind of functionality, but as mentioned, iOS and also Windows 8/Windows Phone 8 only allows you to integrate to the SMS sending application and for SMS reception, there's no proper way to get access to incoming SMS's.

So, with a native container (such as PhoneGap) you could get one step forward with Android, but for other platforms the possibilities are limited to using the native SMS application. If you need to use SMS for some reason in the backend side, services such as Twilio are probably your best shot, but using SMS locally on the device is pretty much a no-go, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I had the same response in SOPT but for my project I needed to send sms on all platforms.