# How to send a Text with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, text, meteor, sms, atmosphere.js

I need to send SMS / text from my Meteor app.

From atmosphere.js, I did find the [presto:zenvia package](https://atmospherejs.com/presto/zenvia), but based on the sample code at that link, it seems it's necessary to first have a zenvia account (must supply username and password), which isn't necessarily a big deal, but the documentation is in a language I do not know (Italian?).

Again, maybe not such a big deal, as Chrome did offer to translate it, and seemed to do pretty good.

However, the most concerning thing is that, according to the history of the project, it is version 0.0.4 and last updated Jun 29, 2015 - several months ago.

Is anyone aware of either a more mature package for sending SMS / texts with Meteor, or more comprehensive samples of just how to use presto:zenvia?

Comment: Have you looked into Twilio?

Comment: @B. Clay Shannon It all depends where you want the app to run and where you want the message to be sent from. Do you want to send the message from your web app running in a browser and pay a per message fee with services like Twilio? Would you rather send an SMS / text via the app running natively on your mobile device the way [Brocator](http://www.brocator.com/) works? The second one I can walk you through.

Comment: I would suggest checking out ecwnye's package which allows you to easily send SMS using Nexmo's API: https://github.com/ecwyne/meteor-nexmo-sms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [`abhiaiyer:meteor-twilio`](https://atmospherejs.com/abhiaiyer/meteor-twilio) package, which lets you hook into the [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) service.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to point you down another route I was aware that cell companies generally have a text messaging email service there is more detail at [Sending SMS to mobile phones via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367225/sending-sms-to-mobile-phones-via-javascript)

but the important bit is as follows

Cellular carriers assign email addresses to their phone numbers and support SMS by email.

So if you can email, you can text.

format : (subscriber 10 digit number)`@sms_providerdomain.xxx`

Alltel `@message.alltel.com` AT&T @txt.att.net Nextel `@messaging.nextel.com` Sprint `@messaging.sprintpcs.com` SunCom `@tms.suncom.com` T-mobile `@tmomail.net` VoiceStream `@voicestream.net` Verizon `@vtext.com` (text only) `@vzwpix.com` (pictures and videos)

as stated by capdragon in 2010 I don't know if this has been updated or changed but I would assume it still holds true today.